# How to address a female interviewer

Tags: politeness

So just had a phone interview, the interviewer was a lady, now that i want to write a thank you letter, how should i address her, Ms or Mrs, because i am not supposed to know she's married or not

Comment: Please don't think I'm being rude, but using Ms or Mrs is probably less important than using a capital 'I' when referring to yourself. ( these fonts don't show it well, it should be `I` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recently as the 1970s and 1980s, usage of "Ms." was perceived by some as a political statement, a rejection of the institution of marriage in favor of feminism. Today, "Ms." is extensively used without controversy in both formal and informal settings, probably because of its obvious usefulness as a way to address a woman whose marital status is unknown.

If anything, "Ms." is probably less likely to give offense than using "Mrs." today, and certainly less likely than "Miss."

Comment: Actually i dont have the interviewers email id but her assistants, who talked to me earlier regarding setting up the interview. So i am emailing him and in the body writing 'thank both you and XXX'. How about not using any salutation, just the name?

Comment: That would depend on the business culture in the interviewer's area and field. Around here, in my field (tech industry,  U.S. West Coast), most interviewers would be perfectly fine being addressed by their first names. Elsewhere, it may be considered less acceptable

Comment: Ok, its Tech industry and Illinois...But anyways i am going to go with Ms. and stop making a big deal out of it..:)..thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Mrs. can be applied to either.  "Dear Sir or Madam:" is typically used as the introduction in business letters, so you may want to use Madam, which is also appropriate for either.

Comment: Actually i dont have the interviewers email id but her assistants, who talked to me earlier regarding setting up the interview. So i am emailing him and in the body writing 'thank both you and XXX'. How about not using any salutation, just the name?